# Route available with or without token JWT+PASSPORT

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, jwt

I want that I can access a router with or without a token. If user has a token, than give me `req.user`

Like this:

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
if(req.user) { // or if (req.isAuthenticated())
 res.send('logged')
} else {
 res.send('not loggedIn')
}
});
```

My app:

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
opts.secretOrKey = 'sh';
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
    }
    if (user) {
        done(null, user);
    } else {
        done(null, false);
        // or you could create a new account
    }
});
}));
```

If I try to access `/profile` without a token, works fine.
But, when a try to access `/profile` with a token in header give me *`not loggedIn`*

I want to access it even without a token and, if I provided a toke, give me the user.

**ps:** Already tested using `passport.authenticate('jwt')` in route and works. If I give token let me access, if not give me unauthorized.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'm doing it:

```
const passport = require('passport');

const optionalJwt = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['authorization']) {
    return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })(req, res, next);
  }
  return next();
};

app.get('/my/route', optionalJwt, function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.send('My name is ' + req.user.name);
  } else {
    res.send('I\'m not authenticated :(');
  }
});
```

It will still fail if the auth header is included but the token has expired or it's invalid, but it might serve the purpose. For me it did.

Answer (score 2):

Change you router as follows

```
router.get('/profile', authenticateUser(), profile());

function authenticateUser(req, res, next) {
  // your strategy here...
  if (authenticated) { 
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } else {
    return res.status(401).send("Not authenticated");
  }
}

function profile(req, res, next) {
  var userId = req.user.id;
  User.findById(userId, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return res.status(500).json(err); }
    return res.json(user);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be using one of the below to access request data

```
if (req.params.user) {do something...}
```

or

```
if (req.body.user) {do something...}
```

the request object has no user attribute.